# How to receive a notification from webview in Angular & Electron app

Tags: angular, electron, angular7

I am using [this package](https://github.com/maximegris/angular-electron) to try integrating Angular 7 with Electron.

In app.html I use  tag to view a web page push notification using HTML5 Notification.

```
<webview partition="somepartition" id="webview1" src="src"></webview>
```

And I have another webview to show another web page

In component ts file, I want to listen to notifications from every webview and show them as a native descktop notifications.

How can I implement this in app.component.ts

Answer (score 0):

You can use ipc communication to send messages from webview to main process. https://electronjs.org/docs/api/notification to implement notification.

Use ipcRenderer.send('notification',{data}) from every webview application. To do this, create a preload script that contains the following which injects ipcRenderer.

```
window.ipcRenderer = require('electron').ipcRenderer;
```

Use the following script from webview application

```
window.ipcRenderer.send('notification',{title:"sample title",body:"sample body" });
```

Note that we are using preload script to avoid nodeIntegration inside webview. 
And in the main process, catch the message using

```
const { Notification , ipcMain } = require('electron');
ipcMain.on('notification',(event,channel,args)=>{
//Write code to show notification notification module
   let notification =  new Notification({ title : args.title , body: args.body });
notification.show();


})
```

Comment: Thank you, I read about that and know how to communicate between processes. My question is how to catch notification from the webview to send it by ipcRenderer?
And I saw that I can not implement this in app.component.ts ?